# Aurelia quick start doesn't work

Tags: aurelia

Did exactly as [tutorial](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start/1) says. Totally copy and pasted then ran in firefox but doesn't render. One thing quick start doesn't address is where to put the html files that we create in the tutorial. DO we put them in the src folder or the main folder? Tried both doesn't work anyway . They have no file structure at the end to show. I'm sure I will get the comments of show your code but that is not what I am asking. I am asking what the file structure should look like.

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: The docs state "In the src folder of your project, create the following file:"

Comment: No it doesn't.  It says that for main.js and app.js but gives no hints as to where to put *.html files.

And I agree with the OP, it doesn't work.  At all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have created a [cli experience](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/1) which totally rocks for beginners.
Check it out. It will probably get you much further much faster.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and for the help and for not being a prick.